# How to display posted data without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a simple react app, witch can GET and POST data to an API. It's a simple gallery where pics are categorized.

At first step I get all galleries from API. That's work fine.

```
class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        galleries: [],
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch('http://.../gallery')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data)=>this.setState({galleries: data.galleries, isLoading: false}))
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false}));
}

render() {
    const {galleries, isLoading, error} = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div className="loader-wrapper"><div className="loader"/></div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className="categories">
            { galleries.length > 0 ? galleries.map((gallery) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={gallery.path}>
                        ...
                    </Card>
                )}) : null
            }          
            <AddCategory/> 
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

At next step you can create new galleries.

```
class AddCategory extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modal: false,
        galleries: [],
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

toggle() {
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    });
}

handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    });
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch('http://.../gallery', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({"name": this.galleryName.value})
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong ...')
            }
        })
        .then((data)=>this.setState({galleries: data.galleries, isLoading: false}))
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false}));
}

render() {
    const {modal, isLoading, error} = this.state;

    if (error) {
        return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div className="loader-wrapper"><div className="loader"/></div>;
    }

    return (
        <Card className="add">
            <div className="link" onClick={this.toggle}>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>Add gallery</CardTitle>
                </CardBody>
            </div>
            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                <div className="modal-header">
                    ...
                </div>
                <ModalBody>
                    <form className="form-inline addCategoryForm">
                        <div className="group">
                            <input type="text" ref={(ref) => {this.galleryName = ref}} id="inputGalleryName" name="galleryName" required/>
                            <label>name of the gallery</label>
                        </div>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} color="success">Add</Button>
                    </form>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </Card>
    );
}
}
```

The problem is that after I click on Add button nothing happened on the page, but after I refresh the page the new gallery is in the list.

Do you have any idea why I get new gallery just after refresh the page, not immediately after click on button Add?

Comment: Because you have two different classes. state is local, and will only apply to the component you add it to.

Comment: Where do you call `AddCategory` component? Is it inside `Home` component's `render()` method or elsewhere?

Comment: Both components are in a different file. But I importing AddCategory to Home and call it after map().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cannot see new galleries in the list without refreshing is that the main component, in this case the `Home` component, is not being re-rendered since there isn't any change in its state variables, so it does not update the page. Your usage of `this.setState` after getting response, from `POST` method using `fetch`, only updates and re-renders sub component `AddCategory`.

Add commented sections below on your components to make `Home` component re-render.

For `Home` component;

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            galleries: [],
            isLoading: false,
            error: null,
        };

        // Add this method binding
        this.updateGalleries = this.updateGalleries.bind(this);
    }

    // Add this method
    updateGalleries = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch('http://.../gallery')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data)=>this.setState({galleries: data.galleries, isLoading: false}))
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false}));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        ...

        return (
            <div className="categories">
                ...  
                /* Add updateGalleries funtion as props to AddCategory */
                <AddCategory updateGalleries={this.updateGalleries}/> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For `AddCategory` component;

```
class AddCategory extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
    }

    toggle() {
        ...
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        ...
        // edit this field after response.json()
        .then((data)=>{
            this.setState({galleries: data.galleries, isLoading: false})
            this.props.updateGalleries();
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false}));
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: now after i click on button Add, i get error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**
`{ galleries.map((gallery) => {`

Comment: can you check if `data.galleries` variable from response.json is **not empty variable** and **it is an array with values in it** before passing to `this.props.updateGalleries(data.galleries)` method ?

Comment: and also be sure that you pass the argument as `data.galleries` to `this.props.updateGalleries(data.galleries)` in your `AddCategory` compenent since I have mistyped it as `this.props.updateGalleries(newGalleriesList)` when I first sent the answer. So, please compare the answer with your changes again. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do everything how you wrote it in your answer, but I still get the same error after clicking on button Add. And also I find a warning in console: **Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
Please check the code for the AddCategory component.**

Comment: prepared a little version of fiddle for you, there is no warning or error. and it re-renders when button is clicked. check out https://jsfiddle.net/kartalerkoc/y36nwex5/

Comment: I think the problem is in fetch POST in **AddCategory**. If I put code from fiddle to the handleClick after click on button Add, it works fine without error.  But if i put back the fetch POST the error message is back.

Comment: yes, that is what I thought also. First, try to fix current problem related to POST method, headers, endpoint or the response from server. Then, come back here and use this answer since it will fix your refresh problem :) hope you solve your problem with the post method soon.

Comment: so finnaly a solve the problem. I modify *updateGalleries* a little bit. I put there the same code as in *componentDidMount* and it look like it works. Maybe it is not the best solution, may it can do better, nicer, I don't know, but it works :) (I edit your code, so you can see how I done it :))

Comment: great to here that your problem is solved! updated the answer, fyi.